# Where is bif: URI?

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso

Solution to my problem requires to use `bif:st_intersects`. I wanted to see the `bif` ontology i.e. to see what is it, and what is exactly `st_intersect`, but on dbpedia [list of namespaces](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), `bif:` does not redirect to any web resource. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bif:st_intersects`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_st_intersects/) is a custom Virtuoso predicate. It works only in Virtuoso,
just as `spatial:intersectBox` works only in Jena. Its definition is rather [operational](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/search?l=C&q=gsop_intersects&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) than ontological.

Additional examples of usage: [1](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtGeoSPARQLEnhancementDocs), [2](http://linkedgeodata.org/OSM); from 2:

> `PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>`